# Stata: Loop up if observation exists

Tags: find, stata

I have a dataset of the following form:

```
vars: 
year, firm, executive

data:
2002, initech, steve
2002, microtech, john
2003, initech, mike
2003, microtech, john
```

I want to add a new variable "sticksaround" that indicates whether a given executive is still with his firm the next year. For my data, I would want the created values to be:

```
0
1
0 or missing (both fine)
0 or missing (both fine)
```

Any thoughts on how I would best go about this?

I was thinking about looping over all observations -- but how do I check if there is an entry with the same executive for the next year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
bysort firm (year): gen sticksaround = executive == executive[_n+1]
```

*E.g.*:

```
clear
input  year str15 firm str5 executive
2002 "initech" "steve"
2002 "microtech" "john"
2003 "initech" "mike"
2003 "microtech" "john"
end

bysort firm (year): gen sticksaround = executive == executive[_n+1]

li
```

Or if you need to compare (*e.g.*) 2002 to 2003, and *not* 2002 to 2004 if 2003 is missing, use `tsset` and try (note that you will need to `encode` `firm` and `executive`):

```
gen sticksaround = executive == F.executive
```

See `help by` and `help tsset` for more information.